# How to print contents of a spinner?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, spinner

Say that I have a spinner that is populated by

`var list = listOf("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five")`

How would I access this list if I wanted to print the contents/dropdown list of the spinner?

I would want an output that's similar to how a list is outputted when the entire thing is printed, like:

`['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI elements like Spinner are not typically used as the owner of data. That would violate the principle of separation of concerns. You should hang onto your array or list reference that you passed to the Spinner and work with it directly. You can call `joinToString()` on it.